# Rails custom validation for specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a user signup form where I am trying to restrict the ability to create an account to users who have a specific access code. I'm running into a problem with being able to validate for that specific code. I've included the code that I've been able to piece together, but isn't working for me.

**#new.html.erb**

```
 <%= f.text_field :access, placeholder: "Access Code", required: "required" %>
```

**#user.rb**

```
validate :check_code
def check_code
  errors.add(:base, 'Try another code') unless User.where(:access == "theAccessCode")
end
```

Can someone suggest an alternative to this validation?

Comment: What is the rule for your validation intended to be?

Comment: Only users with the correct access code should be able to make an account, otherwise they should get the error 'Try another code'.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a single correct access code, I think you want something like this instead:

```
ACCESS_CODE = 'secretCode'
def check_code
  errors.add(:base, 'Try another code') unless self.access == ACCESS_CODE
end
```

Alternatively, your code would probably need to look like this to work (although querying for an existing user still seems wrong):

```
def check_code
  errors.add(:base, 'Try another code') unless User.where(:access => "theAccessCode").exists?
end
```